# Brasero doesn't quit properly

Tags: brasero

I noticed that the Brasero disk burner doesn't open if I have used it before, and it was still running, but invisible. I have to close it with system monitor and then open it again. I was wondering if there is some bug fix for it.

Comment: Which version of brasero are you using @MadTux?

Comment: If you are using Unity and Brasero is still running, then the Brasero icon should show up in the Unity launcher, in which case you can maximize Brasero by clicking on its icon in the Unity launcher.

Comment: @karel it doesn't show up in the launcher, that's the problem.

Comment: OK, now try this. Browse to /usr/share/applications and look for the Brasero icon (it looks like a silver-colored CD). Drag the Brasero icon into the launcher. Click on the Brasero icon in the launcher. Use Brasero, minimize it, and then click on the Brasero icon in the launcher to maximize it again. Please post a comment reporting your results.

Comment: I'm at school now, but I'll try it out at home. Thanks.

Comment: I still want it to quit properly in the first place, though. I don't really want it using up my launcher space all the time.

Comment: It's a terrible idea that using brasero.
my answer is not what you want but when brasero can't write proper you have no right to expect it to open or close proper
just throw it away and use k3b or nero (if you don't concern about free software (free as in freedom))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking the Brasero icon into the launcher is all I can suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I have installed Brasero 3.4.1 into Xubuntu 12.04 and everything works well. It could be one of the Brasero plugins, blocking the process by sitting in a hidden dialog. Try following:

completely remove brasero

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove brasero*
```

and you can let it like this and install k3b or install brasero back again

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brasero
```

or use Ubuntu Software center

Answer (score 0):

Details in this bug report, along with fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/907311

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or is unavailable.